# Re-Use a String or Int througout the whole activity?

Tags: android, performance, android-activity

I didn't realize I've been using one int and one string thoughout the MainAcitivity.

Now I thought about it, I have the feelings that they are going to leak memory.

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button deleteButton;
private String imagePath;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
        deleteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete_button);
        //===== SHARED_PREFERENCES ==============================================================
        SharedPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("SHARED_PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        prefs_editor = SharedPrefs.edit();

         try {
              imagePath = SharedPrefs.getString("ImagePath", "");
            }
        catch (Exception e) {  }    
      }

     .....

     .....

            deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    File file = new File(imagePath);
                    .....

                }
            }); 

            mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    imageLoader.loadImage(imagePath, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                            mImageView.setImageBitmap(loadedImage);                                 
                        }
                    });
                }

public void LoadNextImagePath() {
    File file = new File(LoadUserSavedPathString);
    if(file.isDirectory()) {
        listFile = new File(LoadUserSavedPathString).listFiles();                       
        imagePath = listFile[LastItemPosition-1].getAbsolutePath();
    }
}
```

}

Is this bad and leak memory?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It causes no effect as such. Garbage collection will take care of it. 
Private fields promote encapsulation

It's a generally accepted convention to use private unless you need to expose a field or method to other classes. Getting in this as a habit will save you a lot of pain in the long run.

However, there isn't anything inherently wrong with a public field or method. It causes no difference for garbage collection.

Comment: why do alot of people use String string = " ";  in their methods instead of private String string; at the beginning of the activity?  If the Garbage collection takes care of it, how come the content of the String is still available anytime?  It looks like it has never been trashed by garbage collector?  Thanks

Comment: It depends on the scope you want for that variable. If you don't need it outside the method, then there's no point declaring it outside the method. I don't think you quite understand how garbage collection works. If an object (like an Activity) is in use by the program, then any objects referenced by it are also in use, and thus won't be garbage collected. Whether or not you are doing any meaningful work with that string is irrelevant; if it's reachable by objects in use, then it won't be garbage collected.

Comment: @Karakuri, I am pretty sure I don't understand much about GC, that's why I am asking to understand better.  If the string is declared inside the method and it is not beings used for a while, this string would be trashed by garbage collector, right?  The private strings won't be garbage collected since they are still floating around for use.  I am sorry I just can't understand why these floating private strings are not bad.  So basically, I can freely declare private strings, & re-use them over and over within the MainActivity without any issue?  Thanks for the comment Karakuri.

Comment: Variables declared in a scope are no longer used once you have left that scope. The best way to think of a scope is a pair of brackets: `{}`. If you declare a string between them, once your code passes the closing bracket, that string is no longer in use and can be collected. Naturally, scopes can be nested. The private class member is not bad if you plan to use it in multiple places within that class, and no smaller scope can encapsulate those usages.

Comment: @ Karakuri, thank you so much for well done explanation.  I will write these down on my noteBook.  I  like Android Development and really want to do better.  Thank you very much for all your time to help me.